# how to get value from a list of tuples and make a new list

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have the following:

```
[('first_name', u'Renier'), ('second_name', u''), ('surname', u'de Bruyn'), ('own_transport', u'True'), ('id_number', u'910920254081'), ('id_type', u'IDNumber'), ('id_nationality', u'ZA'), ('disabilities_list', u'Intellectual Disability'), ('disabilities_list', u'Memory Loss'), ('disabilities_list', u'Mental Illness'), ('disabilities_list', u'Physical Disability'), ('disabilities_list', u'Speech and Language Disorders'),...]
```

How would I get the values of these tuples and use, where there is a value `disabilities_list`, to create a new list?

I have tried:

```
 for k in arr:
        if k == "disabilities_list":
            print k # this only returns "disabilities_list" 5 times
```

**Update:**

`arr` is what is returned from a form, this is waht I get when I `print arr`:

```
NestedMultiDict([('first_name', u'Renier'), ('second_name', u''), ('surname', u'de Bruyn'), ('race', u'Caucation'), ('own_transport', u'True'), ('id_number', u'9109205021082'), ('id_type', u'IDNumber'), ('id_nationality', u'ZA'), ('disabitity', u'True'), ('disabilities_list[]', u'Memory Loss'), ('disabilities_list[]', u'Mental Illness'), ('disabilities_list[]', u'Physical Disability'), ('disabilities_list[]', u'Speech and Language Disorders'), ('disabilities_list[]', u'Vision Loss and Blindness'), ('mobile_number', u'0828245092'), ('home_number', u'0317016554'), ('email', u'renierdbruyn@hotmail.com'), ('other_contact', u''), ('line1', u'2 Hamilton Road'), ('line2', u''), ('line3', u''), ('city_town', u'Durban'), ('province', u'GP'), ('postal_code', u'3610'), ('suburb', u'Ashley'), ('country', u'ZA'), ('notice_period', u'4 weeks'), ('for_position', u'Developer'), ('curr_renumeration', u'12.0'), ('expect_renumeration', u'123.0'), ('relocate', u'True')])
```

Comment: Can you show us exactly what the `arr` object is?

Comment: look at the update of my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [list comprehantion](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>>arr = [('first_name', u'Renier'), ('second_name', u''), ('surname', u'de Bruyn'), ('own_transport', u'True'), ('id_number', u'910920254081'), ('id_type', u'IDNumber'), ('id_nationality', u'ZA'), ('disabilities_list', u'Intellectual Disability'), ('disabilities_list', u'Memory Loss'), ('disabilities_list', u'Mental Illness'), ('disabilities_list', u'Physical Disability'), ('disabilities_list', u'Speech and Language Disorders'),...]
>>>
>>>[k[1] for k in arr if k[0] == "disabilities_list[]"] 
[u'Intellectual Disability', u'Memory Loss', ...]
```

**edit**: updated, according to the updated question:

```
>>>[item[1] for item in arr.items() if item[0] == "disabilities_list"]  #  will do, what you want
```

Comment: this returns an empty list `[]`, when I print it out.

Comment: It should not, I have checked it myself.

Comment: I ran type() on arr, and this is what it returns: `<class 'webob.multidict.NestedMultiDict'>`. would this be why its not working for me?

Comment: still returns empty list :/

Comment: because u added [] to "disabilities_list" -> "disabilities_list[]". Updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing that out... haha. it works. @Vahid your answer works as well. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
if k[0] == "disabilities_list":
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
>>> for k,v in arr.iteritems():
...     if k == 'disabilities_list':
...         print v
```